# Pandas dataframe column float inside string (i.e. "float") to int

Tags: string, pandas, floating-point, int, conditional-statements

I'm trying to clean some data in a pandas df and I want the 'volume' column to go from a `float` to an `int`. 
EDIT: The main issue was that the dtype for the `float` variable I was looking at was actually a `str`. So first it needed to be floated, before being changed.
I deleted the two other solutions I was considering, and left the one I used. The top one is the one with the errors, and the bottom one is the solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 #Call the df
t_df = pd.DataFrame(client.get_info())

#isolate only the 'symbol' column in t_df    
tickers = t_df.loc[:, ['symbol']]


def tick_data(tickers):
   for i in tickers:
       tick_df = pd.DataFrame(client.get_ticker())
       tick = tick_df.loc[:, ['symbol', 'volume']]
       tick.iloc[:,['volume']].astype(int)

       if tick['volume'].dtype != np.number:
           print('yes')
       else:
           print('no')
return tick
```

Below is the revised code:

```
import pandas as pd
#Call the df


def ticker():
    t_df = pd.DataFrame(client.get_info())
    #isolate only the 'symbol' column in t_df    
    tickers = t_df.loc[:, ['symbol']]

    for i in tickers:
        #pulls out market data for each symbol
        tickers = pd.DataFrame(client.get_ticker())
        #isolates the symbol and volume
        tickers = tickers.loc[:, ['symbol', 'volume']]
        #floats volume
        tickers['volume'] = tickers.loc[:, ['volume']].astype(float)
        #volume to int
        tickers['volume'] = tickers.loc[:, ['volume']].astype(int)
        #deletes all symbols > 20,000 in volume, returns only symbol
        tickers = tickers.loc[tickers['volume'] >= 20000, 'symbol']        
return tickers
```

Comment: I think you want `if tick['volume'].dtype is not np.number` instead of `!=`. `is` checks whether it is the same class (I might be forgetting some nuance there), while `!=` checks for equal values.

Comment: @Engineero It still shows the same error for each function when applied. When I don't have `tick[:,['volume']].astype(int)` the if/else works, and returns 'yes'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues here.

In your first example, `iloc` only accepts integer locations for the rows and columns in the DataFrame, which is generating your error. I.e.

```
tick.iloc[:,['volume']].astype(int)
```

doesn't work. If you want label-based indexing, use `.loc`:

```
tick.loc[:,['volume']].astype(int)
```

Alternately, use bracket-based indexing, which allows you to take a whole column directly without using slice syntax (:) on the rows:

```
tick['volume'].astype(int)
```

Next, `astype(int)` returns a new value, it does not modify in-place. So what you want is

```
tick['volume'] = tick['volume'].astype(int)
```

As for your dtype is a number check, you don't want to check `== np.number`, but you don't want to check `is` either, which only returns `True` if it's `np.number` and not if it's a subclass like `np.int64`. Use `np.issubdtype`, or `pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype`, i.e.:

```
if np.issubdtype(tick['volume'].dtype, np.number):
```

or:

```
if pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(tick['volume'].dtype):
```

Comment: Did you mean 
`tick[:, ['volume']] = tick.loc[:,['volume']].astype(int)` 
instead of
 `tick['volume'] = tick['volume'].astype(int)`
Or is it not necessary to include the rows?
Also, I changed `tick.iloc[]` to `tick.loc[]` and got some progress out of it. I'm now just getting the error :
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '121489.05100000'`
Which I'm assuming means I need to find a way to deal with the way python processes float-int ending like the '.051.
Not necessarily asking you to solve this new problem for me. More commenting for anyone else that might come here

Comment: `tick.loc[:, col]` is equivalent to `tick[col]` without the rows.Also, you cannot convert a float with decimals directly to int. Round first, e.g. `tick['volume'].round().astype(int)`